# BSODing over memory errors

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, bsod

My Alienware Windows 7 desktop computer has had its history of BSODs and so far I've been able to fix them myself. However, a Windows update that I installed last night and just booted up today seems to BSOD my computer with some sort of memory error (such as `BAD_POOL_HEADER` or `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`) or even just a black screen. I've tried booting into Safe Mode to do a system restore but my computer shuts off before it can restore the system. I've tried a disk check but it just freezes, so I'm not sure what to do here. I do hear 1 beep when it tries to startup and fails as well (it tries to startup 10-20 times before it finally boots up). I tried to boot in safe mode again and it gets stuck on `\Windows\system32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS`.

Comment: Use `Memtestx86+` or `Memtestx86` to verify your memory is operational.

Comment: I'm not sure I can run my computer long enough to install it but I can give it a try as soon as this check disk finishes

Comment: You don't install `Memtestx86` it's a boot environment and boot to it.